# Openlayers in nuxt blob is undefined

Tags: javascript, import, nuxt.js, node-modules, openlayers

I'm trying to make openlayers work in Nuxt but whenever I tried to import openlayers components, I had several errors that I solved, but one of them is "Blob is not defined - node_modules/ol/worker/webgl.js"

I found nothing on openlayers and nuxt and i'm having hard times to just make it work :/

Here is the steps of what I did :

- npm install ol
- made a file with import View from 'ol/View', got error "can't import ESM module...."
- created a plugins folder with a ol.js with all OL assests imported, and added   `plugins: ['@/plugins/ol']` in nuxt.config
  [preview of my ol.js file in my plugins folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4neR.png)
- Got error "can't read fs" file
- added `extend: (config, { isDev, isClient }) => { config.node = {fs: 'empty',}` into my nuxt.config file in build
- Also added `standalone: true,`

and NOW I have blob is undefined and really, I have no clue on what to do to make openlayers work :/

Any help is welcome !

EDIT : Made some changes

- 1 I installed vuelayers
- 2 followed the guide on https://vuelayers.github.io/#/docs/quickstart?id=nuxtjs

edited nuxt.config

```
 plugins: [{
            src: '@/plugins/vuelayers.js',
            ssr: false
        }, { ... }],
    modules: [
                    ...,
            '~/shared/vueLayers',
        ],
```

Create a file shared/ directory named vuelayers.js

```
export default function (moduleOptions) {
    this.options.css.push('vuelayers/lib/style.css')
}
```

- 3 pasted the content of the "simple map example"

I have no error but nothing is displayed on my component yet

Comment: Hi, did you tried this? https://vuelayers.github.io/#/docs/quickstart?id=nuxtjs It's based on an integration for Vue, so everything is here you could probably use this directly.

Comment: Hi thanks, i'll try this ! i'll keep up updated

Comment: ok I have "Cannot use import statement outside a module" event if I had "type"="module" in my package.json :/

Comment: What is your node version here?

Comment: got version 14.17.5

Comment: ok i just fully copy pasted the "Simple map with OSM layer example (editable)" and i have no error but nothing is displayed :o I didnt imported a single component in my map.vue

Comment: How do you import it to have such an error? Can you edit your question please?

Comment: Well, I pasted import { Map, TileLayer, OsmSource, Geoloc } from 'vuelayers' but as it seems, the example given by vuelayer doesn't have any import in the script tag, so I'm a bit confused : I don't need to import anything since I have the plugins/vuelayers.js, right ? I dont have any error but still nothing displayed

Comment: Could you edit your question with all the code that you've tried so far? Or even make a [repro].

Answer (score 2):

The "can't import ESM module...." occurs because the ol package exports [an ES6 module](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/package.json#L34) and when Nuxt is rendered on the server side the parent project uses CommonJS modules. As a result a run time error occurs when the open layers code is not transpiled for server side rendering.

I found there to be two solutions to this problem.

1. Explicitly transpile the Open Layers modules that are used in the `transpile` property of the `build` property in `nuxt.config.js`

   ```
   // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
   build: {
     transpile: [
       'ol/control',
       'ol/proj',
       'ol/style/Circle',
       'ol/style/Fill',
       'ol/format/GeoJSON',
       'ol/format/MVT',
       'ol/Map',
       // ...
     ],
   },
   ```
2. Create a Nuxt plug-in to wrap Open Layers that's only used on the client side similar to the example seen in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dmcd/a59c819dde38d0c4ef3c3288650292b2).

I found the second solution to be cleaner and since Open Layers uses `<canvas>` render the map it can't easily be rendered on the server side anyway.

Note that the Gist linked above is a bit dated, but the idea is still relevant. A modern example might look like the following:

```
// plugins/open-layers.js
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';

export default (context, inject) => {
  const ol = {
    Map,
    View,
  };
  inject('ol', ol);
};
```

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/open-layers.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],
};
```

```
// Parent component
<template>
  <client-only>
    <Map />
  </client-only>
</template>
```

```
// Map.vue
<template>
  <div ref="map" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Map',
   
  methods: {
    renderChart() {
      this.map = new $ol.Map({
        target: this.$refs.map,
        view: new $ol.View({}),
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```